# Use existing EntityFramework class library project with new ASP.NET Core 2.0 Razor Pages project

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I am setting up a new ASP.NET Core 2.0 Razor Pages project, and I want to reuse an existing class library project that has my EntityFramework model, DBContext etc.

Prior to ASP.NET Core 2.0, the approach I took to use a separate EntityFramework project in an MCV website project was:

- To add the EntityFramework project to the solution that has my website project
- Add a reference to the EntityFramework project in the website project
- Copy the connection string from the "app.config" file in the EntityFramework project to the "web.config file" file in the website project.

I am still getting to grips with ASP.NET Core 2, and it seems this approach does not work anymore. "web.config" is now "appsettings.json", and it also seems changes need to be made to the "startup.cs" file.

I have tried the following approach (based on this blog post:
http://jakeydocs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/data/entity-framework-6.html)

- I copied the connection string from the EntityFramework project into "appsettings.json":

  "ConnectionStrings": {
  "BjornsonEntities": "metadata=res://*/BjornsonModel.csdl|res://*/BjornsonModel.ssdl|res://*/BjornsonModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string="data source=COMPUTER_NAME;initial catalog=DB_NAME;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework""
  }
- I included a second constructor for my EntityFramework DBContext class, that takes the connection string:

  ```
  public partial class BjornsonEntities : DbContext
  ```

  {

  ```
  public BjornsonEntities()
      : base("name=BjornsonEntities")
  {}

  public BjornsonEntities(string nameOrConnectionString) : base("name=BjornsonEntities")
  {}
  }
  ```
- And finally I added the following line to ConfigureServices in startup.cs:

  ```
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
  {
      services.AddScoped((_) => new BjornsonEntities(Configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"]));
      services.AddMvc();
  }
  ```

However, when I then try to execute some code to get data from the EntityFramework project, for example like this:

```
var c = new BjornsonEntities();
```

then execution fails in the first DBContext constructor

```
    public partial class BjornsonEntities : DbContext
  {

    public BjornsonEntities()
        : base("name=BjornsonEntities")
    {}
```

I get the following error message:
The type initializer for 'System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig' threw an exception.
FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.

Any suggestions for what goes wrong here? And more specifically, what is the best way to make use of an existing EF project (that is not EF Core) in a separate project? Is there an equivalent, straightforward three-step approach, like the one I described earlier (that works for non ASP-NET-Core projects...)?

**UPDATE**

Initially, the web application project was set up as a .NET Core 2.0 project, not .NET Framework. When the consuming ASP.NET Core web application project is set up as a .NET Framework project the DBContext initialisation mentioned above runs. However, when use the DBContext to try a LINQ query such as the one below

```
        var c = new BjornsonEntities();

        var result = c.PersonEvaluationResponses
            .Where(p => p.PersonEvaluation.ProjectID == 14)
            .Select(p => p).ToList();
```

I get an error that "No connection string named 'BjornsonEntities' could be found in the application config file". There is a connectionstring with this name in appsettings.json, so clearly I'm doing something else wrong, and the connectionstring is not picked up.

Comment: Are you using `.NET Core Framework` or `.NET Framework` when you created the project? I don't think `.NET Core Framework` works with standard `.NET Framework` class library.

Comment: The EntifyFramework project was created with .NET Framework (4.6)... I wanted to re-use an existing project.

Comment: I meant your `ASP.NET Core` Project, when creating from VS2017 you have the option to choose `.NET Core 2.0` or `.NET Framework` from the dropdown.

Comment: Aha, ok. I had initially set the web project up as .NET CORE 2.0. I just tried creating the web application as a .NET Framework project. Now things get further along: the EF DBContext initialises. However, when I try to run a LINQ query I get a message that "No connection string named 'BjornsonEntities' could be found in the application config file.". But there is a connection string with this name in the "appsettings.json" file...?

Comment: Running `Update-Database` does not use `appsettings.json` it uses either `web.config` or `app.config`. Which is what you're `:base()` is doing. You need to pass in your `connectionString` to the `base()`, do that you would have to inject your `appsettings.json` configs to your `Context` class

Comment: Thanks for useful pointers. Having been away from ASP.NET development for a while, I found that the world has changed a lot with .NET Core, standard .Net Framework, running ASP.NET 2.0 Core web application targeting either .Net Core or .Net framework...?!? I found that the most common way to inject appsettings ConnectionString in the Context class is to make use of DbContextOptions, but that type is not available in .Net Framework EntityFramework, only in EntityFramework Core. So in the end I re-created my EntityFramework model in .Net Core, to avoid mixing and matching Frameworks.